# Gem, update and compatibility

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a User model, the user can gradually insert information on their profile (age, description, avatar, etc..).  Those users can be viewed in the public web site only if they have complete their entire profile.

Whats is the best way in rails to put constraint on query without polluting every single call to Active Record User model.  Is there're a way for

```
User.all
```

to return result with those constraints by default?

Tks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a scope.

```
# user.rb
scope :complete, where("age IS NOT NULL", "description IS NOT NULL",...)
```

Then you can just do `User.complete` and it will fetch User objects matching those conditions. For more information:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html